# When I have ratio data and need to apply regression in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I want to apply the logistic regression for x=temperature and y=ratio of male.

If I have a data set like this:

```
X = c(27.2, 27.7, 28.3, 28.4)

Y = c(0, 0, 1, 1)
```

Then I can apply `glm`:

```
glm(Y~X,family=binomial(logit))
```

But I have data like this (sorry I don't know how to explain concisely):

```
X = c(27.2, 27.2, 27.7, 27.7, 28.3, 28.3, 28.4, 28.4)

Y = c(0.1, 0.0, 0.7, 0.67, 1.0, 0.67, 0.70, 0.63)
```

where elements in Y represents ratio of male.

How can I use logistic regression in this case? I'm exhausted searching.

One solution that I think works is to convert the data manually by repeating 100 times for each element. For example if Y=0.1 then make it to be [10 ones, 90 zeros]. But there must be a better solution.

Comment: SO is not the right place to ask this question. I recommend [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). I don't think it is a good thing to discretize your data though. Your problem can be captured by y = (1+e^(-XB))^-1. where B is a vector of coefficients. You could then estimate by maximum likelihood using `optim`. It might be possible to do it directly with glm but I'm not sure.

Comment: You need to provide the number of cases as `weights`, e.g., assuming that each y-value is based on 100 cases: `glm(Y~X,family="binomial", weights = rep(100, 8))`. You know how many animal were studied at each temperature, right? If not, you can't really use logistic regression.

Comment: @Roland Thanks!!